# VPN error 778 between Windows 7 and Debian Squeeze w/ pptpd and AD

Tags: active-directory, vpn, unix

I have a VPN server set up on a debian (lenny) machine. I get an error, 778: "it was not possible to verify the identity of the server", every time I try to connect. I checked the configuration against this site, and set up a replica machine to set it up and test it there as well. On both debian machines, I get a 778.

The wierd thing is, I don't get this error when using a CHAP secrets file; only when using winbind (so as to authenticate over active directory). But we need AD authentication to ensure security in our environment. I have found no literature on this subject other than to update my certificates:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

which I did.

To pose the question, **why am I getting the 778 error and how do I fix the error on a Debian machine?**

EDIT: I found this at http://www.schneier.com/paper-pptpv2.pdf . How MS-CHAPv2 works:

> 1. Client requests a login challenge from the Server.
> 2. The Server sends back a 16-byte random challenge.
> 3. The Client
>      generates a random 16-byte number, called the "Peer Authenticator
>      Challenge."
> 4. The Client generates an 8-byte challenge by hashing
>      the 16-byte challenge received in step (2), the 16-byte Peer
>      Authenticator Challenge generated in step (4), and the Client's
>      username.
> 5. The Client creates a 24-byte reply, using the Windows NT hash function and the 8-byte
>      challenge generated in step (4). This process is identical to
>      MS-CHAPv1.
> 6. The Client sends the Server the results of steps (3)
>      and (5).
> 7. The Server uses the hashes of the Client's password,
>      stored in a database, to decrypt the replies. If the decrypted blocks
>      match the challenge, the Client is authenticated.
> 8. The Server uses
>      the 16-byte Peer Authenticator Challenge from the client, as well as
>      the Client's hashed password, to create a 20-byte \Authenticator
>      Response."
> 9. The Client also computes the Authenticator Response. If the
>      computed response matches the received response, the Server is
>      authenticated.

I suppose then that the Debian machine is not sending the 16-byte Authenticator Challenge or that it is not working correctly. Is there any reason why it would have that problem, and if so, what do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! There error is a SAMBA bug, detailed [here](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6563). Both `squeeze` and `lenny` machines use samba 3.4.8 . I updated via http://backports.debian.org and it worked!

Comment: +1. Good work finding the problem.